# Do Malenti get natural armor bonus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

Malenti are sahuagin appearing as sea elves.

> "If a community of aquatic elves is located within 100 miles of a
>   sahuagin community, about one in one hundred sahuagin looks just like
>   an aquatic elf. These creatures, called malenti, have a swim speed of
>   40 feet, can remain out of water for 1 hour per point of Constitution,
>   and have freshwater sensitivity and light sensitivity (dazzled in
>   bright light). Malenti have no natural attacks. They are otherwise
>   identical with sahuagin." *Monster Manual, p. 218*

If they look just like aquatic elves, they cannot have scales. So: Do malenti have the natural armor bonus of sahuagin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Malenti have the typical sahuagin natural armor bonus

The *Monster Manual* entry on [sahuagin](http://dndsrd.net/monstersS.html#sahuagin) says that mutant sahuagin malenti "have a swim speed of 40 feet, can remain out of water for 1 hour per point of Constitution, and have freshwater sensitivity and light sensitivity [but] have no natural attacks [and] are otherwise identical with sahuagin" (218). Thus a malenti's sahuagin identity *should* extend to a malenti gaining a +5 natural armor bonus just like any other sahuagin, but I totally understand the skepticism: that's a pretty crazy high natural armor bonus for a creature that "looks just like an aquatic elf" (and could be a giveaway as to the malenti's identity in the right situation).

However, to confirm, at least three published malenti gain the natural armor bonus of the sahuagin:

- *City of Stormreach* has **K’shegla**, a malenti of legend cleric 7 (155). He has a Dexterity score of 20 and gains a +5 increase his natural armor bonus from the template monster of legend (*Monster Manual II* 213-4). His AC is listed as 20 normally and when flat-footed and 15 against touch attacks. With no other sources of armor, the natural amor bonus of the sahuagin is the most reasonable source of this unmentioned-by-the-text bonus to Armor Class. (Also, K’shegla's illustration looks *nothing* like an aquatic elf, but that's hardly his fault.)
- More telling, *Secrets of Xen'drik* has the unfortunately-named **Korel**, a malenti expert 1/rogue 2 (64-5). The sources of Korel's Armor Class bonuses are actually detailed: she receives a +3 bonus from her Dexterity, a +2 armor bonus, and—for no other reason that I can discern except for her malenti heritage—a +5 natural armor bonus to Armor Class.
- The Web adventure ["Shoals of Intrigue"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20030228a) has **Medjil**, a malenti Drd 4 (6). Her AC 18 (touch 12, flat-footed 16) is a product of her Dexterity score of 14, her *bracers of armor +1*, and—presumably—her sahuagin identity, no other source conveniently explaining her +5 bonus to AC.

While three *is* a really small sample size, the malenti is a fairly obscure monster—a 1-in-100 mutant offspring of an evil underwater race—, so having three sources that agree that the malenti receive the sahuagin natural armor bonus should, I hope, be enough.

Comment: Wow, perfect research.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes.

Aside from the listed features the block clearly states "They are otherwise identical to Sahagin."

Comment: But isn't +5 natural armor a bit too much for, say, tough skin?

Comment: @Giorin That’s personal opinion, and not something this site is really equipped to discuss.

Comment: @Giorin Similarly, it's a bit much that waving your arms and shouting nonsense produces consistent magical results. But that's how the game works.

Comment: @Giorin The entry on natural armor bonuses just says "naturally tough hide". It doesn't care how specifically that is accomplished in a physics sense. Since the rules say it is possible for hide to be +5, then it is, regardless of how that is pulled off. You could say the scales are sub-dermal or something if you can't deal with magical physics?

Comment: @nijineko Thanks, that was, what I was looking for: some sort of definition that included skin that could look like aquatic elf.

Comment: @Giorin You are most welcome. Often enough the rules which were intended to be vague enough to aid DMs in their freedoms, becomes a shackle which trips both players and DMs all too frequently.